# How can I prevent page break between lines of a paragraph or bibliography entry?

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, paragraphs

My university's thesis guidelines require that each bibliographic entry appear in whole on a single page, rather than being split across two. How can I prevent (La)TeX breaking a paragraph across a page boundary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify the variable that tells TeX how bad an idea it is to break up lines of a paragraph as follows:

```
\interlinepenalty=10000
```

The `10000` there means TeX will never do this. This could mean that a long paragraph could even overrun the bottom of a page. If you just want to make a strong suggestion, use a smaller number.

Comment: In addition, you might want to add some stretchy glue between paragraphs `\parskip0pt plus\baselineskip` so that TeX will feel free to stretch out the spaces between the paragraphs/bibliography entries to fill the page.

Comment: How would one get that added between each bibliography entry and the next?

Comment: @SamB: Probably a `\bgroup \interlinepenality=10000 \parskip0pt plus\baselineskip \thebibliography \egroup` would do it (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

If the page breaks are occurring where there are `\par`s in the `.bbl` file, edit the bibliography style file by adding a `\nobreak` after each. Note that editing BibTeX style files is not for the faint of heart. `texdoc btxhak` seems to be the only documentation available.