# bibliography entry all on one page (formatting)

Tags: bibliographies

I am using a .bib file and am trying to program my .cls file to print the bibliography so that every entry is on complete and not broken up on different pages. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you check out the posting [How can I force bibliography items not to be split across pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51257/5001)?

Comment: Amazing... I am using apacite...and it worked!  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
\interlinepenalty=10000
\bibliography{example}   Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Since the answers given in the earlier posting appear to work for your setup as well, I will suggest that this posting be closed as a duplicate. This doesn't mean that you posted a bad question -- only that an earlier posting addressed the same issue(s).