# How to add page breaks between citations for printbibliography

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, bibliographystyle

I'm working on my grad thesis and I sent a draft to the school's office. I got back a few formatting nitpicks that I'm working on now. One issue has been a bit harder to fix, so I'm going to post the question here.

I am using the standard `\printbibliography` command to grab everything from `main.bib` and generate a properly formatted set of references. However when I generate it, a few citations end up split across two pages. That is not something the school wants and I will need to fix this.
[image]

They gave me a LaTeX template with a bunch of formatting rules but evidently these rules are not sufficient.

```latex
\addbibresource{main.bib}
\newcommand{\buildBibliography}{
    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\hspace{-0.1em} References}
    \begin{centering}
    \textbf{References}\\
    \end{centering}
    \begin{singlespace}
    \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip} 
    % \interlinepenalty=10000
    % \widowpenalty=10000
    % \clubpenalty=10000
    \printbibliography[title={}]
    \end{singlespace}
}
```

I have tried setting various penalties at high values, as noted [in other questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51257/how-can-i-force-bibliography-items-not-to-be-split-across-pages/51259#51259) but those aren't having an effect on my document. Maybe they're doing something different. I have not been able to figure out how to force a line break. Is there some other kind of hack I can try?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks! It's been a useful resource in the past, though this is one time when the existing answers have not been able to help.