# Bold-face author name in bibliography and add ", and" before the last author in the list

Tags: bibliographystyle

I'm entirely new to LaTeX and I'm trying to format my bibliography where I want to make a specific author name bold-face and also add `, and` before the last author's name. [image]

I've skimmed through some of the existing answers but I failed to make anything work so far.

This is the LaTeX code that I'm using in the .cls file.

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesClass{awesome-cv}[2017/02/05 v1.6.1 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Class options
%
% (need to be done before the external package loading, for example because
% we need \paperwidth, \paperheight and \@ptsize to be defined before loading
% geometry and fancyhdr)
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Options for draft or final
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
% Inherit options of article
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                3rd party packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Needed to make fixed length table
\RequirePackage{array}
% Needed to handle list environment
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% Needed to handle text alignment
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
% Needed to configure page layout
\RequirePackage{geometry}
% Needed to make header & footer efficiently
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
% Needed to manage colors
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
% Needed to use \ifxetex-\else-\fi statement
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
% Needed to use \if-\then-\else statement
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
% Needed to strip chars from telephone number
\RequirePackage{xstring}
% Needed to use a toolbox of programming tools
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
% Needed to change line spacing in specific environment
\RequirePackage{setspace}
% Needed to manage fonts
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
% To support LaTeX quoting style
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
% Needed to manage math fonts
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
% Needed to use icons from font-awesome
\RequirePackage{fontawesome5}
\RequirePackage{roboto}
\RequirePackage[default,opentype]{sourcesanspro}
% Needed for the photo ID
\RequirePackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
% Needed to deal a paragraphs
\RequirePackage{parskip}
% Needed to deal hyperlink
\RequirePackage[hidelinks,unicode,pdfpagelabels=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  pdftitle={},
  pdfauthor={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfkeywords={}
}
% Solves issues Warning: File `cv.out' has changed
\RequirePackage{bookmark}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for directory locations
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure an optional directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
% Not required anymore but left in place for backward compatability.
\newcommand*{\fontdir}[1][fonts/]{\def\@fontdir{#1}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for layout
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Page Layout
% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=2.0cm, top=1.5cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, footskip=.5cm}

%% Header & Footer
% Set offset to each header and footer
\fancyhfoffset{0em}
% Remove head rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Clear all header & footer fields
\fancyhf{}
% Enable if you want to make header or footer using fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Gray-scale colors
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}
% Basic colors
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
% Text colors
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
\colorlet{text}{darkgray}
\colorlet{graytext}{gray}
\colorlet{lighttext}{lightgray}
\colorlet{sectiondivider}{gray}
% Awesome colors
\definecolor{awesome-emerald}{HTML}{00A388}
\definecolor{awesome-skyblue}{HTML}{0395DE}
\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\definecolor{awesome-pink}{HTML}{EF4089}
\definecolor{awesome-orange}{HTML}{FF6138}
\definecolor{awesome-nephritis}{HTML}{27AE60}
\definecolor{awesome-concrete}{HTML}{95A5A6}
\definecolor{awesome-darknight}{HTML}{131A28}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}

% Boolean value to switch section color highlighting
\newbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}
\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{true}

% Awesome section color (only for first 3 characters)
%\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
%  \ifbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{{\color{awesome}#1#2#3}}{#1#2#3}%
%}
% Awesome section color (for the entire heading)
\def\@sectioncolor{\color{awesome}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for fonts
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\headerfont}{\roboto}
\newcommand*{\headerfontlight}{\robotolight}
\newcommand*{\footerfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfont}{\sourcesanspro}
\newcommand*{\bodyfontlight}{\sourcesansprolight}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure styles for each CV elements
% For fundamental structures
\newcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{text} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7.6pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headeraddressstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\headerfont\itshape\color{lighttext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headersocialstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\headerfont\color{text} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerquotestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\itshape\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\footerstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\footerfont\scshape\color{lighttext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{16pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
\newcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\textcolor{text}{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\paragraphstyle}{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\upshape\color{text}}

% For elements of entry
\newcommand*{\entrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\slshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\descriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9.5pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\upshape\color{text} #1}}

% For elements of subentry
\newcommand*{\subentrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\mdseries\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\slshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subdescriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\upshape\color{text} #1}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for extra
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Define helper macros a user can change easily
% Header
\newcommand{\acvHeaderNameDelim}{\space}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterNameSkip}{.4mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterPositionSkip}{.4mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterAddressSkip}{-.5mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderIconSep}{\space}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterSocialSkip}{6mm}
\newcommand{\acvHeaderAfterQuoteSkip}{5mm}

% Others
\newcommand{\acvSectionTopSkip}{3mm}
\newcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{2.5mm}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for utilities
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% Use to draw horizontal line with specific thickness
\def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}

% Use to execute conditional statements by checking empty string
\newcommand*{\ifempty}[3]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for elements of CV structure
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define a header for CV
% Usage: \makecvheader
\newcommand*{\makecvheader}[1][C]{%
  \newcommand*{\drawphoto}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{}{%
      \newlength{\photodim}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoshape}{circle}}%
        {\setlength{\photodim}{1.3cm}}%
        {\setlength{\photodim}{1.8cm}}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoedge}{edge}}%
        {\def\@photoborder{darkgray}}%
        {\def\@photoborder{none}}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[\@photoshape, draw=\@photoborder, line width=0.3mm, inner sep=\photodim, fill overzoom image=\@photo] () {};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }
  \newlength{\headertextwidth}
  \newlength{\headerphotowidth}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}{
    \setlength{\headertextwidth}{\textwidth}
    \setlength{\headerphotowidth}{0cm}
  }{%
    \setlength{\headertextwidth}{0.76\textwidth}
    \setlength{\headerphotowidth}{0.24\textwidth}
  }%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\headerphotowidth}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoalign}{left}}{\raggedright\drawphoto}{}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\headertextwidth}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\raggedright}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{\raggedleft}{\centering}}
    \headerfirstnamestyle{\@firstname}\headerlastnamestyle{{}\acvHeaderNameDelim\@lastname}%
    \\[\acvHeaderAfterNameSkip]%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@position}}{}{\headerpositionstyle{\@position\\[\acvHeaderAfterPositionSkip]}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}{}{\headeraddressstyle{\@address\\[\acvHeaderAfterAddressSkip]}}%
    \headersocialstyle{%
      \newbool{isstart}%
      \setbool{isstart}{true}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \href{\@teluri}{\faMobile*\acvHeaderIconSep\@mobile}%
          \setbool{isstart}{false}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{mailto:\@email}{\faEnvelope[regular]\acvHeaderIconSep\@email}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@dateofbirth}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          % \mbox prevents wrapping of elements%
          \mbox{\faBirthdayCake\acvHeaderIconSep\@dateofbirth}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{http://\@homepage}{\faHome\acvHeaderIconSep\@homepage}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://github.com/\@github}{\faGithub\acvHeaderIconSep\@github}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@gitlab}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://gitlab.com/\@gitlab}{\faGitlab\acvHeaderIconSep\@gitlab}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@bitbucket}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://bitbucket.com/\@bitbucket}{\faBitbucket\acvHeaderIconSep\@bitbucket}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@stackoverflowid}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/\@stackoverflowid}{\faStackOverflow\acvHeaderIconSep\@stackoverflowname}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\faLinkedinIn\acvHeaderIconSep\@linkedin}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@orcid}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://orcid.org/\@orcid}{\faOrcid\acvHeaderIconSep\@orcid}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@twitter}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://twitter.com/\@twitter}{\faTwitter\acvHeaderIconSep\@twitter}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mastodonname}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://\@mastodoninstance/@\@mastodonname}{\faMastodon\acvHeaderIconSep\@mastodonname}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \faSkype\acvHeaderIconSep\@skype%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@reddit}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.reddit.com/user/\@reddit}{\faReddit\acvHeaderIconSep\@reddit}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@researchgate}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.researchgate.net/profile/\@researchgate}{\faResearchgate\acvHeaderIconSep\@researchgate}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@xing}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.xing.com/profile/\@xing}{\faXingSquare\acvHeaderIconSep\@xing}
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@medium}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://medium.com/@\@medium}{\faMedium\acvHeaderIconSep\@medium}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@kaggle}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://kaggle.com/\@kaggle}{\faKaggle\acvHeaderIconSep\@kaggle}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@hackerrank}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://www.hackerrank.com/\@hackerrank}{\faHackerrank\acvHeaderIconSep\@hackerrank}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@googlescholarid}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \href{https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=\@googlescholarid}{\faGraduationCap\acvHeaderIconSep\@googlescholarname}%
        }%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}%
        {}%
        {%
          \ifbool{isstart}{\setbool{isstart}{false}}{\acvHeaderSocialSep}%
          \@extrainfo%
        }%
    } \\[\acvHeaderAfterSocialSkip]%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
      {}%
      {\headerquotestyle{\@quote\\}\vspace{\acvHeaderAfterQuoteSkip}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[c]{\headerphotowidth}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@photoalign}{right}}{\raggedleft\drawphoto}{}
  \end{minipage}
}

% Define a footer for CV
% Usage: \makecvfooter{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
\newcommand*{\makecvfooter}[3]{%
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\footerstyle{#1}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footerstyle{#2}}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\footerstyle{#3}}
}

% Define a section for CV
% Usage: \cvsection{<section-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionTopSkip}
  \sectionstyle{#1}
  \phantomsection
  \color{sectiondivider}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
}

% Define a subsection for CV
% Usage: \cvsubsection{<subsection-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-3mm}
  \subsectionstyle{#1}
  \phantomsection
}

% Define a paragraph for CV
\newenvironment{cvparagraph}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-3mm}
  \paragraphstyle
}{%
  \par
  \vspace{2mm}
}

% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \ifstrempty{#5}
      {}
      {\multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\}
  \end{tabular*}%
}

% Define an environment for cvsubentry
\newenvironment{cvsubentries}{%
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define a subentry of cv information
% Usage: \cvsubentry{<position>}{<title>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cvsubentry}[4]{%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \setlength\leftskip{0.2cm}
    \subentrytitlestyle{#2} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {\subentrydatestyle{#3}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {}
      {\subentrypositionstyle{#1} & \subentrydatestyle{#3} \\}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}
      {}
      {\multicolumn{2}{L{17.0cm}}{\subdescriptionstyle{#4}} \\}
  \end{tabular*}
}

% Define an environment for cvhonor
\newenvironment{cvhonors}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}\ifempty{#2}{}{,} \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}


\newlength{\category}
\settowidth{\category}{Operating systems} % Category with longer text 
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
    \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
    \vspace{-2.0mm}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} R{\category} L{\textwidth -\category -2\tabcolsep}} % changed <<<<<<<<
}{%
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}

% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{%
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-4.0mm}
}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Bibliography
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\RequirePackage[ % BibLaTeX
    sorting=ydnt, % Sorts entries by year (descending order), name, title
    style=verbose,
    doi=true,
    isbn=true,
    url=true,
    eprint=false,
    backref = false, % include back references in bibliography
    maxcitenames=3, % affects only the citations in the document body
    maxbibnames=99, % affects only the bibliography, pass 99 to print all
    hyperref=true,
    block=none,
    backend=biber % {Options: bibtex, biber}
    ]{biblatex}

% Avoid splitting entries across page break (only for 3 or fewer lines)
% Tip: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51261
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
   \clubpenalty10000
   \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
   \widowpenalty10000
   \interlinepenalty5000}

% Customized format, based on the Fancy CV template created by Adrien Friggeri
% See https://github.com/ashee/cv (MIT license)
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1\par}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\color{graytext}%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
%    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
%    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\color{graytext}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\color{graytext}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\color{graytext}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\color{graytext}%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

% New syntax for flexible backend (BibLaTeX > v3.3)
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \nameparts{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
    {\ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartfamily, \namepartgiven\adddot}%
    }%
    {\ifblank{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\space\namepartfamily, \namepartgiven\adddot}}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
  {}
}
```

This is the `test.tex` file

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% Awesome CV LaTeX Template for CV/Resume
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV
%
% Author:
% Claud D. Park <posquit0.bj@gmail.com>
% http://www.posquit0.com
%
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
%


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CONFIGURATIONS            
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
    
% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}

\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}

\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{true}
    
\addbibresource{test_ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{test_pub.tex}

\end{document}
```

This is the `test_pub.tex`

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% SECTION TITLE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cvsection{Publications}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% SUBSECTION TITLE
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cvsubsection{Peer-reviewed articles}

\begin{refsection}
    \nocite{servant2015HiCPro}
    \nocite{hsieh2015Mapping}


    \printbibliography[
    heading=none, 
    sorting=ydnt
    ]
\end{refsection}
```

This is the `test_ref.bib`

```
@article{servant2015HiCPro,
    title = {{HiC}-{Pro}: an optimized and flexible pipeline for {Hi}-{C} data processing},
    volume = {16},
    issn = {1474-760X},
    shorttitle = {{HiC}-{Pro}},
    url = {https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-015-0831-x},
    doi = {10.1186/s13059-015-0831-x},
    language = {en},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2020-06-14},
    journal = {Genome Biology},
    author = {Servant, Nicolas and Varoquaux, Nelle and Lajoie, Bryan R. and Viara, Eric and Chen, Chong-Jian and Vert, Jean-Philippe and Heard, Edith and Dekker, Job and Barillot, Emmanuel},
    month = dec,
    year = {2015},
}

@article{hsieh2015Mapping,
    title = {Mapping {Nucleosome} {Resolution} {Chromosome} {Folding} in {Yeast} by {Micro}-{C}},
    volume = {162},
    issn = {00928674},
    url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0092867415006388},
    doi = {10.1016/j.cell.2015.05.048},
    language = {en},
    number = {1},
    urldate = {2020-06-14},
    journal = {Cell},
    author = {Hsieh, Tsung-Han S. and Weiner, Assaf and Lajoie, Bryan and Dekker, Job and Friedman, Nir and Rando, Oliver J.},
    month = jul,
    year = {2015},
    pages = {108--119}
}
```