# Can I configure bibtex.exe to insert the command \interlinepenalty=10000 in the .bbl file?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, page-breaking, compiling, options

The following question-answers show a method of avoiding page-breaks in between references:
[How can I prevent page break between lines of a paragraph or bibliography entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28/8303)
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51259/8303

The answers which suggest inserting `\interlinepenalty=10000` are simple and work really well. However, each time `bibtex` compiles the `.bbl` file, I have to manually edit it for inserting the interline penalty command. Then I have to run my `.bat` file all over again after commenting out the `bibtex.exe` command.

Since this is a bit cumbersome, is there a way I could configure `bibtex.exe` to do it for me?

Comment: Continuing with my approach related to most of the things that don't work out the straight way (usually because of me being ignorant of the straight way), I am currently writing a `Python` script to do this repetitive task for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add

```
@preamble{"\interlinepenalty=10000 "}
```

in the `.bib` file, the instruction will appear before `\begin{thebibliography}`. If you want it to hold only in the `thebibliography` environment, just patch `\thebibliography`.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \apptocmd\thebibliography{\interlinepenalty=10000 }{}{}%
}
```

should do.

Comment: I didn't understand the difference between the two solutions you have provided. If I add `@preamble{"\in...}` in the `.bib` file, the instruction will appear before `\begin{thebi...}`. Why is this different from your second solution, in that why will it affect environments other than the `thebibliography` environment?

Comment: @ShashankSawant The `\@preamble` solution makes the setting to `\interlinepenalty` hold until `\end{document}`. If the bibliography is the last thing in the document, it's obviously the simplest strategy. With the “patch” method, the change is limited to the environment and ends with `\end{thebibliography}`.

Answer (score 1):

The field `@preamble` is there for things like these.

```
@preamble{"\interlinepenalty=10000"}
```